# How to get navigation duration with traffic from google maps api?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to get the navigation duration from google maps api with http request:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=src&destination=destination

but i get the duration without traffic.
how can i get the duration with traffic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Google Directions API, it states that:

```
duration_in_traffic indicates the total duration of this leg, taking into account current traffic conditions. The duration in traffic will only be returned if all of the following are true:

1.The directions request includes a departure_time parameter set to a value within a few minutes of the current time.
2.The request includes a valid Google Maps API for Work client and signature parameter.
3.Traffic conditions are available for the requested route.
4.The directions request does not include stopover waypoints.
```

So you need to meet all the above requirements in order to retrieve duration with traffic.

For more information, you can visit [the Leg section](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#Legs) of the Google Directions API documentation.

Answer (score 7):

You are now able to get `duration_in_traffic` without a premium account (just a standard API key from [the developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library) with the "Google Maps Directions API" enabled). Verify in your browser with

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Brooklyn&destination=Queens&departure_time=now&key=YOUR_KEY_HERE`

It appears that the javascript client uses a different endpoint that does not yet return `duration_in_traffic`.

The request must meet the following conditions, as updated in [the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#traffic-model):

> - The request includes a departure_time parameter.
> - The request includes a valid API key, or a valid Google Maps APIs Premium Plan client ID and signature.
> - Traffic conditions are available for the requested route.
> - The request does not include stopover waypoints.
> - The request is specifically for driving directions— the mode parameter is set to driving.

Comment: Thank you for this point : departure_time MUST be present (even if its value is default = "now") !