# Google Directions Javascript API Doesn't Return Duration_In_Traffic

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to use google direction JavaScript API to estimate a trip duration in traffic but for some way it's not returned as a part of the JSON array 
anyway here's how I call the service

```
        ser.route(
        {
            'origin': Markers[0].position,
            'destination': Markers[Markers.length - 1].position,
            'waypoints': wayPoints,
            'travelMode': google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
            'provideRouteAlternatives': true,
            drivingOptions: {
                departureTime: new Date (Date.Now),
                trafficModel: google.maps.TrafficModel.BEST_GUESS
            }
```

but when I try to get the duration in traffic this way

```
var minutes = element.legs[0].duration_in_traffic.value;
```

firebug returns

> element.legs[0].duration_in_traffic is undefined

I'm pretty sure the region is traffic supported but I can't know why the duration in traffic isn't returned

Comment: Can you add the `origin` and `destination` values you used?

Comment: @Nicolas origin (27.0790288, 33.85765659999993) destination (27.1786308, 33.80094929999996)

Comment: And what did you set in `wayPoints`? Maybe you should add your complete code

Comment: the way points is empty but I don't think it's relevant @Nicolas I already stated it's not a support issue the region is supported

Comment: So have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28074732/how-to-get-navigation-duration-with-traffic-from-google-maps-api

Comment: @Nicolas thanks for your help but that wasn't very helpful to me as it doesn't use the API and the I already made sure and knew all those steps

Comment: I think you did not understand: if you don't have a valid Google Maps API for Work client and signature parameter, you won't have any traffic info.
If you don't add more info about the way you are calling Google Maps API, we can't help you more

Comment: @nicolas-r is right. Based on the [Distance Matrix Service API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix)

> The duration_in_traffic is only returned to Google Maps API for Work customers where traffic data is available, the mode is set to driving, and departureTime is included as part of the distanceMatrixOptions field in the request.

Answer (score 1):

This problem appears to be limited to the javascript client. You can make a GET request to the Directions API from your browser as described in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28074732/how-to-get-navigation-duration-with-traffic-from-google-maps-api/34714307#answer-34714307).

Comment: 2016 -> Same problem. With method GET OK, and with javascript Service KO. I don't understand why ...